# Convert query from Mysql to Eloquent Laravel

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I need Help to Convert Mysql Query to Eloquent Laravel

```
 SELECT SUM((id_user=7) * `commission_agent`) AS sum7,SUM((id_user=8) * `commission_agent`) as sum8 FROM agents_commission
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have the agents commission model set up correctly, you can use something like:

`AgentCommission::select(DB::raw("SUM((id_user=7) *`commission_agent`) AS sum7,SUM((id_user=8) *`commission_agent`) as sum8"))->from(agents_commission)->get();`

Comment: @muhammad what problem are you having?